# TypeScript compiler unable to find immutable.js Map iterator in for of loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use immutable.js with TypeScript but having a hard time convincing the compiler that a `Map` has an iterator. The code works in ES6 so I am not sure why it doesn't work in TypeScript.

**Code**

```
import {Map} from "immutable";

const m = Map({ a: 1 });

for (const [key, value] of m) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

**Expected output:**

`a 1`

**Actual:**

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
src/test.ts (6,28): Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. (2488)
```

**ES6 example:**

```
const Immutable = require( "immutable");

const m = Immutable.Map({ a: 1 });

for (const [key, value] of m) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

**Output:**

`a 1`

**Extra notes:**

I have also tried `m.entries()` and `m.entrySeq()` all produce the same error.

I am using TypeScript 2.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the definition file for `immutable.js` doesn't include this, but you can add it yourself:

```
import {Map} from "immutable";

declare module "immutable" {
    interface Map<K, V> {
        [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[K,V]>;
    }
}

const m = Map({ a: 1 });

for (const [key, value] of m) { // should be fine
    console.log(key, value);
}
```